# Repeat a Unix command every x seconds forever

Tags: command-line, scripting

There's a built-in Unix command `repeat` whose first argument is the number of times to repeat a command, where the command (with any arguments) is specified by the remaining arguments to `repeat`.

For example,

```
% repeat 100 echo "I will not automate this punishment."
```

will echo the given string 100 times and then stop.

I'd like a similar command – let's call it `forever` – that works similarly except the first argument is the number of seconds to pause between repeats, and it repeats forever.  For example,

```
% forever 5 echo "This will get echoed every 5 seconds forever and ever."
```

I thought I'd ask if such a thing exists before I write it. I know it's like a 2-line Perl or Python script, but maybe there's a more standard way to do this. If not, feel free to post a solution in your favorite scripting language.

PS: Maybe a better way to do this would be to generalize `repeat` to take both the number of times to repeat (with -1 meaning infinity) and the number of seconds to sleep between repeats.
The above examples would then become:

```
% repeat 100 0 echo "I will not automate this punishment."
% repeat -1 5 echo "This will get echoed every 5 seconds forever."
```

Comment: Why not: repeat [-t time] [-n number] command [args...]?

Comment: Jonathan, repeat doesn't actually work that way, you're just proposing an improvement to my syntax, right?  I think you're right.  But see the "watch" command in gbrandt's answer.  I think that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately both on my Ubuntu and my AIX *repeat* is **command not found**. Can you do a `type repeat` and let me know where's coming from?

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu and don't have repeat installed. Any information on how to install this would be helpful.

Comment: `repeat` is a builtin command in csh and tcsh.

Comment: Maybe you can use `watch` - I do not know if it is available for osx. It runs a program periodically and show its output.

Comment: @KeithThompson, csh, tcsh **and zsh**. Though it's more a keyword than a builtin

Comment: All your examples are totally useless. Can't you just show what you're trying to reach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299704/run-command-every-second

Comment: Try my [bash repeat function](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111504/27653) with fine granularity and duration check.

Answer (score 818):

Try the `watch` command.

```
Usage: watch [-dhntv] [--differences[=cumulative]] [--help] [--interval=<n>] 
             [--no-title] [--version] <command>`
```

So that:

```
watch -n1  command
```

will run the command every second (well, technically, every one second plus the time it takes for `command` to run as `watch` (at least the `procps` and `busybox` implementations) just sleeps one second in between two runs of `command`), forever.

Would you want to pass the command to `exec` instead of `sh -c`, use `-x` option:

```
watch -n1 -x command
```

---

On macOS, you can get `watch` from [Mac Ports](http://www.macports.org/):

```
port install watch
```

Or you can get it from [Homebrew](http://brewformulas.org/Watch):

```
brew install watch
```

Comment: Aha, thanks!  I don't have that on my system (Mac OS X) -- do you have a link?

Comment: you can use MacPorts to install it.  sudo port install watch

Comment: fink has a package...

Comment: Also available in homebrew (brew install watch).

Comment: +1 For a new powerful tool. I used to `while true; do X; sleep Y; done` - This is way better.

Comment: Problem with this tool (on Ubuntu at least) is that it forces fullscreen, so if I'm dumping some periodic info, I lose the previous info.

Comment: It is called `cmdwatch` on FreeBSD (from the ports: `sysutils/cmdwatch`).

Comment: This is pretty cool. I wanted to run `sensors` repetitively. Now all I have to do is type `watch sensors`.

Comment: Is there a way to use watch with fractions of a second instead of only integers?

Comment: but... how can i stop this infinite loop if i used to log to file in background?

Comment: How do I keep it from clearing the screen? i want the output over and over

Comment: Damn, I thought it was a dirty hack.............

Comment: **Beware:** `watch` seems to have trouble with commands that produce more than one screen of output. If you have a shell script that produces a lot of output then **commands following the command that overflooded the screen won't be executed**. This hasn't been thoroughly tested, so YMMV.

Comment: be careful if you use a piped command. Enter the command in ticks to be save like: watch -n 1 'grep test file.txt | wc -l'

Comment: `watch` now has `-p` switch which stricly runs command every n seconds.

Comment: Beware that `watch` requires a terminal attached to the command execution environment, which is not always the case, e.g., in system startup scripts.

Answer (score 348):

**Bash**

`while` + `sleep`:

```
while true
do 
    echo "Hi"
    sleep 1
done
```

Here's the same thing as a shorthand one-liner (From the comments below):

```
while sleep 1; do echo "Hi"; done
```

Uses `;` to separate commands and uses `sleep 1` for the `while` test since it always returns true. You can put more commands in the loop - just separate them with `;`

Comment: Cool, thanks; which shell is that?  But note that I'm looking for something you execute as a single command-line command.

Comment: I believe it works as written in a generic Bourne shell, as well.

Comment: @dreeves, using ";" as separator, commands can be execeted in a single line. Look at Toony's answer as a example

Comment: sleep 1 always returns true so you can use it as the while condition. Not the most readable thing in the world but absolutely legit: while sleep 1; do echo "Hi"; done

Comment: I myself like the shorthand `while :; do echo Hi; sleep 1; done`.

Comment: @David Costa: You made a reasonable point, but `sleep` doesn’t *always* return true. Ī̲ used such loops (albeit with longer delay) namely because there is a way to terminate it gracefully with killing the sleep process.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I didn't think of it, it actually returns zero only when the time has passed and non-zero when it is terminated by a signal. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: To do a date time clock: `while sleep 1; do clear && date; done`

Comment: This runs the command once every second-and-then-some. If it weren't `echo hi`, but rather "Do something for 0.5 seconds" - your period time would be 1.5 seconds

Answer (score 101):

This is just a shorter version of other `while+sleep` answers, if you are running this kind of tasks often as your daily routine, using this saves you from unnecessary key presses, and if your command line starts to get longer understanding this one is a bit easier. But this one starts with sleeping first.

This is generally useful if you need to follow something has one-line output like machine load:

```
while sleep 1; do uptime; done
```

Comment: Yes.  This should be documented next to UUOC.

Comment: And if you want it to operate like "watch" you can do `while clear; do date; command;sleep 5; done`

Comment: Wow, thanks for ``while sleep`` combination, saves keystokes!

Comment: `while sleep ...` is a good solution if you want colored output. `watch` does not provide colored output by default (I'm sure there is some way to get it, but this answer is fast and easy.)

Answer (score 48):

One problem that all the answers posted so far have is that the time the command is executed can drift.  For example, if you do a `sleep 10` between commands, and the command takes 2 seconds to run, then it's going to run every 12 seconds; if it takes a variable amount of time to run, then over the long term the time when it runs can be unpredictable.

This might be just what you want; if so, use one of the other solutions, or use this one but simplify the `sleep` call.

For one-minute resolution, cron jobs will run at the specified time, regardless of how long each command takes.  (In fact a new cron job will launch even if the previous one is still running.)

Here's a simple Perl script that sleeps until the next interval, so for example with an interval of 10 seconds the command might run at 12:34:00, 12:34:10, 12:34:20, etc., even if the command itself takes several seconds.  If the command runs more than `interval` seconds, the next interval will be skipped (unlike cron).  The interval is computed relative to the epoch, so an interval of 86400 seconds (1 day) will run at midnight UTC.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if (scalar @ARGV < 2) {
    die "Usage: $0 seconds command [args...]\n";
}

$| = 1;  # Ensure output appears

my($interval, @command) = @ARGV;

# print ">>> interval=$interval command=(@command)\n";

while (1) {
    print "sleep ", $interval - time % $interval, "\n";
    sleep $interval - time % $interval;
    system @command; # TODO: Handle errors (how?)
}
```

Comment: See also [this other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50722)

Comment: simpler in bash to minimize drift (though it may drift over very long usage windows due to the sleep command and bash itself accumulating its tiny execution times):

`while :; do sleep 1m & command; wait; done`

Comment: @math: Clever. It doesn't work if you have other background processes running in the current shell (`wait` will wait for all of them). That's fixable by changing `wait` to `wait $!`, where `$!` is the PID of the `sleep` process. Post this as an answer and I'll upvote it. But it does produce some extraneous output in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 44):

I think all the answer here so far are either too convoluted, or instead answer a different question:

- *"How to run a program repeatedly so that there are X seconds delay between when the program finished, and the next starts"*.

The real question was:

- *"How to run a program every X seconds"*

These are two very different things when the command takes time to finish.

Take for instance the script `foo.sh` (pretend this is a program that takes a few seconds to complete).

```
#!/bin/bash
# foo.sh
echo `date +"%H:%M:%S"` >> output.txt;
sleep 2.5;
# ---
```

You wish to run this every second, and most would suggest `watch -n1 ./foo.sh`, or `while sleep 1; do ./foo.sh; done`. However, this gives the output:

```
15:21:20
15:21:23
15:21:27
15:21:30
15:21:34
```

Which is not exactly being run every second. Even with the `-p` flag, as the `man watch` page suggests might solve this, the result is the same.

An easy way to accomplish the desired task, which some touch on, is to run the command in the background. In other words:

```
while sleep 1; do (./foo.sh &) ; done
```

*And that is all there is to it.*

You could run it every 500 ms with `sleep 0.5`, or what have you.

Comment: Those who voted on different answers, do not understand the elegance of your answer...

Comment: This is good unless your program has side effects. If the program takes longer than the interval, the side effects can interfere (like overwriting a file). If the program waits for something else, and that something else is taking forever, then you're starting more and more background jobs indefinitely. Use with caution.

Comment: could invert the order of the backgrounding to ensure that not more than one ./foo.sh is run at a time, but no faster than 1 per second:

`while :; do sleep 1 & ./foo.sh; wait; done`

Comment: Yes, it will drift, a few milliseconds on each loop, but it will. Make `date +"%H:%M:%S.%N"` in foo.sh to see how the fraction will increase slowly on each loop.

Comment: Yes, it's true that most answers don't _literally_ address the question. But it's an almost safe bet that they answer what the OP wanted. It would be a safer bet if the OP had actually accepted an answer... But this is good, _provided_ you are aware of possible side effects _and_ you are certain that the average run time of the command is not going to exceed the cycle time

Answer (score 17):

In `bash`:

```
bash -c 'while [ 0 ]; do echo "I will not automate this punishment in absurdum."; done'
```

(`echo` could be replaced by any command...

Or in `perl`:

```
perl -e 'for (;1;) {print "I will not automate this punishment in absurdum.\n"}'
```

Where `print "I will not automate this punishment in absurdum.\n"` could be replaced with "any" command surrounded with backticks (`).

And for a pause, add a `sleep` statement inside the for loop:

```
bash -c 'while [ 0 ]; do echo "I will not automate this punishment in absurdum."; sleep 1; done'
```

and

```
perl -e 'for (;1;) {print "I will not automate this punishment in absurdum.\n"; sleep 1}'
```

Comment: `while [ 0 ]` is a bad way to write it.  It means `0` is a string with length > 0.  `while [ 1 ]` or `while [ jeff ]` would do the same thing.  Better to write `while true`.

Comment: @Mikel: Or `while :`

Answer (score 12):

### Recent bash >= 4.2 under recent Linux kernel, based answer.

In order to limit execution time, there is **no forks**! Only built-in are used.

For this, I use `read` builtin function instead of `sleep`. Unfortunely this won't work with *notty* sessions.

#### Quick [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function "`repeat`" as requested:

```
repeat () {
   local repeat_times=$1 repeat_delay=$2 repeat_foo repeat_sleep
   read -t .0001 repeat_foo
   if [ $? = 1 ] ;then
       repeat_sleep() { sleep $1 ;}
   else
       repeat_sleep() { read -t $1 repeat_foo; }
   fi
   shift 2
   while ((repeat_times)); do
        ((repeat_times=repeat_times>0?repeat_times-1:repeat_times))
        "${@}"
        ((repeat_times))&& ((10#${repeat_delay//.})) &&
            repeat_sleep $repeat_delay
   done
}
```

Little test with quoted strings:

```
repeat 3 0 printf "Now: %(%T)T, Hello %s.\n" -1 Guy
Now: 15:13:43, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:13:43, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:13:43, Hello Guy.

repeat -1 .5 printf "Now: %(%T)T, Hello %s.\n" -1 Guy
Now: 15:14:14, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:14, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:15, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:15, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:16, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:16, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:17, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:17, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:18, Hello Guy.
Now: 15:14:18, Hello Guy.
^C
```

#### Depending on granularity and duration of submitted command...

Under recent Linux kernels, there is a procfile `/proc/timer_list` containing time information in nanoseconds.

If you want to run a command exactly once by second, your command has to end in less than a second! **And** from there, you have to *`sleep`* only the *rest* of current second.

If the delay is more important and your command doesn't require significant time, you could:

```
command=(echo 'Hello world.')
delay=10
while :;do
    printf -v now "%(%s)T" -1
    read -t $(( delay-(now%delay) )) foo
    ${command[@]}
  done.
```

But if your goal is to obtain finer granularity, you have to:

#### Use nanoseconds information to wait until begin of a second...

For this, I wrote a little bash function:

```
# bash source file for nano wait-until-next-second

mapfile  </proc/timer_list _timer_list
for ((_i=0;_i<${#_timer_list[@]};_i++));do
    ((_c+=${#_timer_list[_i]}))
    [[ ${_timer_list[_i]} =~ ^now ]] && TIMER_LIST_READ=$_c
    [[ ${_timer_list[_i]} =~ offset:.*[1-9] ]] && \
        TIMER_LIST_OFFSET=${_timer_list[_i]//[a-z.: ]} && \
        break
done
unset _i _timer_list _c
readonly TIMER_LIST_OFFSET TIMER_LIST_READ
waitNextSecondHires() {
    local nsnow nsslp
    read -N$TIMER_LIST_READ nsnow </proc/timer_list
    nsnow=${nsnow%% nsecs*}
    nsnow=$((${nsnow##* }+TIMER_LIST_OFFSET))
    nsslp=$((2000000000-10#${nsnow:${#nsnow}-9}))
    read -t .${nsslp:1} foo
}
```

After sourcing them, you could:

```
command=(echo 'Hello world.')
while :;do
    waitNextSecondHires
    ${command[@]}
  done.
```

run `${command[@]}` directly on command line, than compare to

```
command=(eval "echo 'Hello world.';sleep .3")
while :;do
    waitNextSecondHires
    ${command[@]}
  done.
```

this must give exactly same result.

#### Hires [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function "`repeat`" as requested:

You could source this:

```
mapfile  </proc/timer_list _timer_list
for ((_i=0;_i<${#_timer_list[@]};_i++));do
    ((_c+=${#_timer_list[_i]}))
    [[ ${_timer_list[_i]} =~ ^now ]] && TIMER_LIST_READ=$_c
    [[ ${_timer_list[_i]} =~ offset:.*[1-9] ]] && \
        TIMER_LIST_OFFSET=${_timer_list[_i]//[a-z.: ]} && \
        break
done
unset _i _timer_list _c
readonly TIMER_LIST_OFFSET TIMER_LIST_READ

repeat_hires () {
    local repeat_times=$1 repeat_delay=$2 repeat_foo repeat_sleep repeat_count
    read -t .0001 repeat_foo
    if [ $? = 1 ] ;then
        repeat_sleep() { sleep $1 ;}
    else
        repeat_sleep() { read -t $1 repeat_foo; }
    fi
    shift 2
    printf -v repeat_delay "%.9f" $repeat_delay
    repeat_delay=${repeat_delay//.}
    read -N$TIMER_LIST_READ nsnow </proc/timer_list
    nsnow=${nsnow%% nsec*}
    started=${nsnow##* }
    while ((repeat_times)); do
        ((repeat_times=repeat_times>0?repeat_times-1:repeat_times))
        "${@}"
        ((repeat_times)) && ((10#$repeat_delay)) && {
            read -N$TIMER_LIST_READ nsnow </proc/timer_list
            nsnow=${nsnow%% nsec*}
            nsnow=${nsnow##* }
            (( (nsnow - started) / 10#$repeat_delay - repeat_count++ )) &&
                printf >&2 "WARNING: Command '%s' too long for %f delay.\n" \
                           "${*}" ${repeat_delay:0:${#repeat_delay}-9
                           }.${repeat_delay:${#repeat_delay}-9}
            printf -v sleep "%010d" $((
                10#$repeat_delay - ( ( nsnow - started ) % 10#$repeat_delay ) ))
            repeat_sleep ${sleep:0:${#sleep}-9}.${sleep:${#sleep}-9}
        }
    done
}
```

Then try it:

```
time repeat_hires 21 .05 sh -c 'date +%s.%N;sleep .01'
1480867565.152022457
1480867565.201249108
1480867565.251333284
1480867565.301224905
1480867565.351236725
1480867565.400930482
1480867565.451207075
1480867565.501212329
1480867565.550927738
1480867565.601199721
1480867565.651500618
1480867565.700889792
1480867565.750963074
1480867565.800987954
1480867565.853671458
1480867565.901232296
1480867565.951171898
1480867566.000917199
1480867566.050942638
1480867566.101171249
1480867566.150913407

real    0m1.013s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.016s

time repeat_hires 3 .05 sh -c 'date +%s.%N;sleep .05'
1480867635.380561067
WARNING: Command 'sh -c date +%s.%N;sleep .05' too long for 0.050000 delay.
1480867635.486503367
WARNING: Command 'sh -c date +%s.%N;sleep .05' too long for 0.050000 delay.
1480867635.582332617

real    0m0.257s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: `read -t` is a **built-in**, while `sleep` is not. This could have border effect (ie hitting [key:return] interrupt quietly the *sleep*), but this could be treated by testing `$foo`

Answer (score 5):

If your intention is not to display a message to your screen, and if you could afford to repeat the job in terms of minutes, [crontab](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/), perhaps, would be your best tool. For example, if you wish to execute your command every minute, you would write something like this in your `crontab` file:

```
* * * * * my_precious_command
```

Please check out the tutorial for further example. Also, you can set the timings easily using [Crontab Code Generator](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php).

Answer (score 5):

Bash and some of its kindred shells have the convenient `(( ... ))` notation wherein arithmetic expressions can be evaluated.

So as an answer to your third challenge, where both the repeat count and delay between each repeat should be configurable, here's one way to do it:

```
repeat=10
delay=1

i=0
while (( i++ < repeat )); do
  echo Repetition $i
  sleep $delay
done
```

This answer also suffers from the timing drift covered in [*Keith's* answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28935/17666).

Answer (score 4):

#### Perl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# First argument is number of seconds to sleep between repeats, remaining
# arguments give the command to repeat forever.

$sleep = shift;
$cmd = join(' ', @ARGV);

while(1) {
  system($cmd);
  sleep($sleep); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this out (Bash):

```sh
forever ()   {
    TIMES=shift;
    SLEEP=shift;
    if [ "$TIMES" = "-1" ]; then
        while true;
        do
            $@
            sleep $SLEEP
        done
    else
        repeat "$TIMES" $@
    fi; }
```

Comment: I'm not to hot at shell, so improvements welcome.  And I don't seem to have a "repeat" command in my distro.

Comment: `repeat` is specific to csh and tcsh.

Comment: @KeithThompson: and zsh

Answer (score 4):

What if we had both ?

Here's the idea : with only "interval", it repeats forever. With "interval" and "times", it repeats this number of times, separated by "interval".

The usage :

```
$ loop [interval [times]] command
```

So, the algorithm will be :

- List item
- if $1 contains only digits, it is the interval (default 2)
- if $2 contains only digits, it is the number of times (default infinite)
- while loop with these parameters

  - sleep "interval"
  - if a number of times has been given, decrement a var until it is reached

Therefore :

```
loop() {
    local i=2 t=1 cond

    [ -z ${1//[0-9]/} ] && i=$1 && shift
    [ -z ${1//[0-9]/} ] && t=$1 && shift && cond=1
    while [ $t -gt 0 ]; do 
        sleep $i
        [ $cond ] && : $[--t]
        $@
    done
}
```

Comment: Note: it does not work with floats, despite `sleep` does accept them.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by gbrandt, if the `watch` command is available, definitely use it.  Some Unix systems, however, don't have it installed by default (at least they don't where I work).

Here's another solution with slightly different syntax and output (works in BASH and SH):

```
while [ 1 ] ; do
    <cmd>
    sleep <x>
    echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>" `date` ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
done
```

Edit: I removed some "." in the last echo statement...holdover from my Perl days ;)

Comment: `while [ 1 ]` only works because 1 is treated as a string, just like `while [ -n 1 ]`.  `while [ 0 ]` or `while [ jeff ]` would do the same thing.  `while true` makes much more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the power from python interpreter from shell.

```
python3 -c "import time, os
while True:
    os.system('your command')
    time.sleep(5)
```

replace five in any time(sec) you like.

Attention: the return use SHIFT+ENTER to return input in shell. And do not forget to type 4 **SPACE** indent in each line in while loop.

Comment: Note that `python`'s `os.system()` executes a shell to interpret the command line, so invoking `python` to  run shells in a loop to run a command periodically is a bit overkill. You might as well do everything in the shell.

Comment: I agree with you. However, there is a 5 second sleep as you described in each loop. Thus the extra cost from starting a new shell can be ignored. If this cost make the period longer than expectation, you can reduce some sleep time as requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I wound up up creating a variant on swalog's answer.  With his you had to wait X seconds for the first iteration, I'm also running my in the foreground so..

```
./foo.sh;while sleep 1; do (./foo.sh) ; done
```

Comment: What do the parens around ./foo.sh do? And why the additional ./foo.sh in the front?

Answer (score 1):

Quick, dirty and probably dangerous to boot, but if you're adventurous and know what you're doing, put this into `repeat.sh` and `chmod 755` it,

```
while true
do 
    eval $1 
    sleep $2 
done
```

Invoke it with `./repeat.sh <command> <interval>`

My spidey sense says this is probably an evil way of doing this, is my spidey sense right?

Comment: Eval!?  What for?  `sleep $1; shift; "$@"` or similar would be much better.

Comment: Dunno why this is -2.  eval may be overkill... except when you need it. Eval lets you get things like redirection onto the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a script from init (adding a line to /etc/inittab). This script must run your command, sleep for the time you want to wait until run the script again, and exit it. Init will start your script again after exit.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works on [Mac OS X v10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion). It works wonderfully.

```
bash -c 'while [ 0 ]; do \
      echo "I will not automate this punishment in absurdum."; done'
```

In my case

```
bash -c 'while [ 0 ]; do ls; done'
```

or

```
bash -c 'while [ 0 ]; do mv "Desktop/* Documents/Cleanup"; done'
```

to clean up my desktop constantly.

Comment: Did you mean to have a `sleep` command there?

Comment: `while [ 0 ]` is an odd way to write an infinite loop; it works because the `test` command (also known as `[`) treats a non-empty string as true.  `while : ; do ... ; done` is more idiomatic, or if you prefer you can use `while true ; do ... ; done`.

Answer (score 0):

To repeatedly run a command in a console window I usually run something like this:

`while true; do (run command here); done`

This works for multiple commands as well, for example, to display a continually updating clock in a console window:

`while true; do clear; date; sleep 1; done`

Comment: Why the downvote? You can see this is a working solution by copy and pasting the example into a terminal window.

Comment: I think you got down voted because it is a little bit dangerous and consumes the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/sh

# Run all programs in a directory in parallel
# Usage: run-parallel directory delay
# Copyright 2013 by Marc Perkel
# docs at http://wiki.junkemailfilter.com/index.php/How_to_run_a_Linux_script_every_few_seconds_under_cron"
# Free to use with attribution

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
   echo
   echo "run-parallel by Marc Perkel"
   echo
   echo "This program is used to run all programs in a directory in parallel" 
   echo "or to rerun them every X seconds for one minute."
   echo "Think of this program as cron with seconds resolution."
   echo
   echo "Usage: run-parallel [directory] [delay]"
   echo
   echo "Examples:"
   echo "   run-parallel /etc/cron.20sec 20"
   echo "   run-parallel 20"
   echo "   # Runs all executable files in /etc/cron.20sec every 20 seconds or 3 times a minute."
   echo 
   echo "If delay parameter is missing it runs everything once and exits."
   echo "If only delay is passed then the directory /etc/cron.[delay]sec is assumed."
   echo
   echo 'if "cronsec" is passed then it runs all of these delays 2 3 4 5 6 10 12 15 20 30'
   echo "resulting in 30 20 15 12 10 6 5 4 3 2 executions per minute." 
   echo
   exit
fi

# If "cronsec" is passed as a parameter then run all the delays in parallel

if [ $1 = cronsec ]
then
   $0 2 &
   $0 3 &
   $0 4 &
   $0 5 &
   $0 6 &
   $0 10 &
   $0 12 &
   $0 15 &
   $0 20 &
   $0 30 &
   exit
fi

# Set the directory to first prameter and delay to second parameter

dir=$1
delay=$2

# If only parameter is 2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30 then automatically calculate 
# the standard directory name /etc/cron.[delay]sec

if [[ "$1" =~ ^(2|3|4|5|6|10|12|15|20|30)$ ]]
then
   dir="/etc/cron.$1sec"
   delay=$1
fi

# Exit if directory doesn't exist or has no files

if [ ! "$(ls -A $dir/)" ]
then
   exit
fi

# Sleep if both $delay and $counter are set

if [ ! -z $delay ] && [ ! -z $counter ]
then
   sleep $delay
fi

# Set counter to 0 if not set

if [ -z $counter ]
then
   counter=0
fi

# Run all the programs in the directory in parallel
# Use of timeout ensures that the processes are killed if they run too long

for program in $dir/* ; do
   if [ -x $program ] 
   then
      if [ "0$delay" -gt 1 ] 
      then
         timeout $delay $program &> /dev/null &
      else
         $program &> /dev/null &
      fi
   fi
done

# If delay not set then we're done

if [ -z $delay ]
then
   exit
fi

# Add delay to counter

counter=$(( $counter + $delay ))

# If minute is not up - call self recursively

if [ $counter -lt 60 ]
then
   . $0 $dir $delay &
fi

# Otherwise we're done
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to repeat a job from crontab with an interval less than one minute (20 seconds example)  :

crontab:
* * * * * script.sh

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
>>type your commands here.

sleep 20
>>retype your commands here.

sleep 20
>>retype your commands here.
```

Comment: Have you heard of loops? Invented about 60 years ago or more.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh` and a `sleep` implementation that accepts  floating-point arguments:

```
typeset -F SECONDS=0 n=0
repeat 100 {cmd; sleep $(((n+=3) - SECONDS))}
```

Or for `forever`:

```
for ((;;)) {cmd; sleep $(((n+=3) - SECONDS))}
```

If your `sleep` doesn't support floats, you can always redefine it as a wrapper around `zsh`'s `zselect` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
sleep() zselect -t $((($1 * 100) | 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
until ! sleep 60; do echo $(date); command; command; command; done
```

works for me.

1. I don´t need it exactly every 60 seconds
2. "watch" does not watch commands on all systems
3. "watch" can take only one command (or a script file)
4. putting the sleep in the condition instead of the body makes the loop better interruptable (so a claim in a reply to a similar question on stackoverflow. unfortunately I can find it at the moment)
5. I want to execute it once before the delay, so I use until instead of while

Comment: I just noticed that "until" apparently executes the sleep before the first iteration too. is there any way of putting the condition at the end of the loop in bash?

Answer (score -2):

... I wonder how much complicated solutions can be created when solving this problem.

It can be so easy...

```
open /etc/crontab
```

put there 1 next line to the end of file like:

```
*/NumberOfSeconds * * * * user /path/to/file.sh
```

If you want to run something every 1 second, just put there:

```
*/60 * * * * root /path/to/file.sh 

where that file.sh could be chmod 750 /path/to/file.sh
```

and inside of that file.sh should be:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#What does it do
#What is it runned by

your code or commands
```

and thats all!

ENJOY!

Comment: This is not correct. */60 is going to run every 60 minutes, and */5, for example, every 5 minutes.

Comment: seconds is not allowed on crontab