# high precision subsecond cronjob replacement

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I am looking for a cron replacement which could run subsecond schedule, is there have any "still alive" project which serve this purpose?

Currently running Ubuntu 14

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43185/run-unix-command-precisely-at-very-short-intervals-without-accumulating-time-lag

Comment: Maybe that script could help? It should be easily adaptable for delays < 1s.

Comment: I haven't used systemd yet, but maybe systemd timers could be used for this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? There'll be a delay due to the time it takes for cron to launch an external program. With subsecond precision, that delay is non-negligible. You should probably include the fine timer directly in your application for minimal lag.

Comment: I want to execute task based on second, for example: 15:23:37 execute echo

Currently Ubuntu doesn't use systemd (I think it's RHEL7 thing)

Answer (score 0):

There don't seem to be any well-supported tools in existence for this. I'd say the right way to do this is to [build a daemon](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html). You can build a daemon in almost any language you're comfortable with. In Java, for example, you could use [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to handle the scheduling aspect, and you can find many examples online of how to write a daemon in Java. Python or Perl would probably be a more appropriate tool to use in a *nix environment, however.