# running script at specific times without using cron

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to run a shell script in (`#!/bin/sh` in HP-UX) on exact times(hh:mm:ss) hh:05:00 .. hh:10:00 .. hh:15:00 .. hh:20:00 .. hh:25:00 and so on.
I understand this could be done using `cron` but I'm looking for another way to do this.

Adding: watch/repeat are not supported

Comment: In your case, start at hh:05:00, run every 300 seconds.

Comment: Or: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43185/run-unix-command-precisely-at-very-short-intervals-without-accumulating-time-lag

Comment: Why you do not want to use cron?

Comment: cron is disabled for the system

Comment: Do you have python or perl installed?

Comment: perl v5.8.3 is installed
no python

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
sleep $(($(date --date="14-JAN-2015 17:00" +%s) - $(date +%s)))
run command ...
```

where `14-JAN-2015 17:00` is the date and time you want to wait until.

To run every five minutes, you can consider that the seconds returned by `date` will be a multiple of 300 on 5 minute boundaries, so this will calculate the difference between now and the next five minute boundary (returning between 0 and 299):

```
timeNow=$(date +%s)
sleepTime=$(( ( ( $timeNow + 299) / 300 * 300 ) - $timeNow ))
sleep $sleepTime
```

If `date +%s` is not available, try:

```
timeNow=$(awk 'END { print systime() }' /dev/null)
```

Adding: also worked with:

```
perl -e 'print time(), "\n" '
```

Comment: well .. script run time is about 2minutes .. i want to wait untill time is hh:mX:ss where X is equal to (0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55)

Comment: Using my suggested method, you would have to generate the next start time using some date arithmetic based on the current time, which is possible, but a bit fiddly. You can do date arithmetic with date. I will see if I can think of something.

Comment: I used something similar .. assign script run time in a variable 'x'
then do 'sleep 300 - x' ... with doing this and running the script at hh:mX:00 .. with X is equal to any of the values i mentioned earlier .. it works, but after a while there are delays introduced .. so it is no longer running at hh:mX:00 .. instead hh:mX:0[1,2,3] ... DELAYS

Comment: With my version, it subtracts the current time, so delays will not accumulate.

Comment: Exactly what I'm doing and getting delays,
I'm using $SECONDS which is basically a seconds counter.. I assign it to $a at the beginning of script run and to $z at the end of the script, then do "sleep 300-(b-a)" ... getting delays accumulated over time.

Comment: Yes - you will get errors over time. At some point you need to anchor on the actual time by running the date command, as in the example above.

Comment: date: bad format character - s
I think the date version is too old to support %s

Comment: Adding: also worked with:
perl -e 'print time(), "\n" '