# Use an alias with watch command

Tags: alias, watch

The post [repeat command every x seconds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever) shows that `watch` is the utility that is useful for the invoking a command at fixed interval repeatedly.

Now, I have very long commands, and have used aliases to group them logically to get a quicker output, like

```
$ alias c1='grep "checking for" file1.log'
$ alias c2='grep "validated" file1.log'
$ (echo "Checking: "`c1`) && (echo "Validated: "`c2`)
```

The output of 3rd command is like

```
Checking: 100
Validated: 80
```

It is a long running process, I need to check the status of this process, to get the mentioned counts. But invoking the above with `watch` gives error

> $ watch '(echo "Checking: "`c1`) && (echo "Validated: "`c2`)'
>   c1 command not found

I can put the entire command in there and remove the aliases, but is there any other work-around to get the aliases working with `watch` command?

**Note:** Did quickly go through the man page for `watch`, but didn't find any reference to `alias` in specific.

Comment: Yup, not sure you'd seen that one before.