# How to start a command every 5 seconds on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, watch

How to start a command for example `ls -la` every 5 seconds on Solaris ? . I'm searching for something like  `watch -n 5 ls -la`

Comment: and what's wrong with `watch` ?

Comment: @Carpette, I'm not sure it comes with a default Solaris installation; I see a 3rd-party package available at https://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWwatch/

Comment: FWIW OpenCSW is a pretty common repo for installing software on Solaris. I would just as a matter of best practice have it available unless you have a reason to leave it off (security clearance or some such).

Answer (score 6):

You can make a script using `sleep`, as described in [this ticket](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10647/83944)
Basically, this make something like that:

```
while true
do 
    ls -la
    sleep 5
done
```

You can launch this in a screen if you want to reach it at any moment, or you can redirect the output in a file that you can consult at any time (because i think `screen`, as `watch`, isn't installed with the basic solaris installation).

Answer (score 1):

Building on both answers by @Carpette and @AmitSanghvi:

Loops of the form

```
while true
do
    ...
    sleep 5
done
```

can be notoriously difficult to interrupt with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.  On the other hand, the `sleep` interval is a prime target for keyboard interruption.

Better is:

```
while sleep 5
do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on the earlier answer by @Carpette ... here's a parameterised version of the same script.

```bsh
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "ERROR: Syntax is script <command> interval"
  exit
fi

while true
do
  eval "${1}"
  echo "
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
"
  sleep $2
done
```

Example usage:

```bsh
~/scripts/watch.sh "tail -10 /oracle/home/alert.log" 5
```