# filter top result

Tags: text-processing, command-line, grep, top

I'm using macOS Sierra and I would like to log a process with the `top` command and store all the information in a file. I'm using the following command:

```
top | grep --line-buffered "PROCESS" > test.txt
```

This perfectly works, but I would like to select only certain columns as the reseults:

1. PID
2. Memory Usage
3. CPU Usage
4. Network Usage
5. Disk Usage

Is there a way to filter the `top` result and select only the columns of my interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this command in a loop.

```
top -l 1 | grep "PROCESS" | awk '{print $1,$2}' >> test.txt
```

Use `awk` to select the respective columns you want to include in your logs. For example, `$1` is the first column, `$2` is the second and so on.

Comment: invalid option or syntax: -b

Comment: @user1849976 Try now. I've edited the answer

Comment: Ok, now the command works, but how to run it once a second?

Comment: Try the watch command or sleep in bash. See:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever

Comment: can use `awk '/PROCESS/{print $1,$2}'` instead of grep + awk combo :)

Comment: @Sundeep yea that should work as well

Comment: @Sundeep thank you for your tips, it works :)